# Multitail without TTY

Tags: logging

I have an older app that I am migrating to run in Docker on Kubernetes. As such, I would like to expose its logs to the standard output of the container, so that Kubernetes can see it properly.

The thing is, the app logs into files in a particular directory. The files may appear throughout the lifespan of the application (therefore plain `tail -f *` is not an option).

I have gotten my hands on this [multitail](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/examples.php) tool which looks very promising. The following does almost what I need:

```
multitail -Q 'var/log/*.log'
```

But in this form it creates a new window (like `vim` or `less` would do) and I can't find a way to convince it to not try to allocate a TTY and just plain stream the logs to its stdout (like `tail -f` would do).  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Looking for the exact same thing... have you found any reasonable solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It doesn't seem possible with multitail

Comment: I confirm it doesn't. I'm using xtail (https://salsa.debian.org/debian/xtail) as a workaround

Answer (score 0):

The following sidecar container would be able to tail any dynamically created log file/files inside a dynamically created folder. I created the alpine linux docker image with inotifytools installed in it(**apk upgrade && apk add inotify-tools**)

```
- name: tail-sidecar
  image: alpine:inotify-tools
  command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - |
      touch var/log/tail_out.log
      while ! ls /var/log/**/*.log > /dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 0.5; done; tail -q -f /var/log/**/*.log 1> var/log/tail_out.log 2> /dev/null &
      while true; do inotifywait -e create -r /var/log && tailpid=$!; kill -9 $tailpid; tail -q -f /var/log/**/*.log 1> var/log/tail_out.log 2> /dev/null & done > /dev/null 2>&1 &
      tail -f /var/log/tail_out.log
  volumeMounts:
  - name: varlog
    mountPath: /var/log
```